# Opening a terminal on startup

Tags: command-line, startup

Is there any way for me to force a brand new terminal to open upon starting up Ubuntu? I'd like to just get going in a new terminal every time I restart without having to click and open it.

I've poked around in the Startup Applications Preferences to try and get it to become a designated startup program, but I wasn't sure where the terminal is as an actual installed program on my hard drive (if it even is).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this just add a new start up application with the following command:

```
gnome-terminal
```

Thats it!